# C++ MySql connector issues

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am writing a C++ program in Visual Studio 2019 that connects to a local MySql Database using C++ MySql connector. I am using the example code provided on the MySQL website.

```
sql::Driver* driver;
sql::Connection* con;
sql::Statement* stmt;
sql::ResultSet* res;


driver = get_driver_instance();
con = driver->connect("localhost", "root", "password");

con->setAutoCommit(0);


con->setSchema("testdatabase");

stmt = con->createStatement();
res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT TestCode FROM testdatabase.test;");
delete res;
delete stmt;
delete con;
```

However I keep getting the same errors, no matter what I try:

[image: The errors]

I'm pretty sure it's related to this line of code, as removing it gets rid of the error

```
driver = get_driver_instance();
```

Does anyone know what causes this? I have been searching for an answer for hours and can't seem to find a fix

Comment: Looks like you are missing linking to an import library.

Comment: Looks like the `check` function is declared in your code, have you forgotten to define it?

Comment: You're missing the required `lib` file. How did you install the library? Did you use a package manager?

Comment: @WBuck I read an answer to a question somewhere on stack overflow that said I only needed to use #include then the file path for four of the files included in the Connector file. How exactly do I install a library?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @botje It more or less confirms what I already know about the error but it doesn’t completely answer my question. I think I have found a way to fix it. I just have to see if it works.